# Using Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1 works for small searches - sometimes

Tags: perl, twitter

I am trying to search for tweets about Art Trails with a Perl program using the Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1 module. Sometimes it works sometimes it returns nothing but 200: OK.
The smaller the number of results I request the more likely it is to work. It is not an issue with the Twitter limits. Could it be something to do with timing of the data return?

```
use Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1;

my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1->new(
  traits   => [qw/OAuth API::RESTv1_1/],
  consumer_key        => $c1,
  consumer_secret     => $c2,
  access_token        => $c3,
  access_token_secret => $c4,
  ssl  => 1,
  legacy_lists_api => 0
  );

my $maxresults = 10;

eval {
my $r = $nt->search('"art walk" OR "artists walk" OR "art walks" OR "artist walks" OR "artist trail" OR "artist trails" OR "art trail" OR "art trails" -filter:retweets' ,{ count => $maxresults});

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $r;

};

print $@;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out what was going on, but I got around the problem by putting the request into a loop and retrying the request with ever diminishing max results. And it seems that I am now consistently getting a result.